# Architecture - how to run SP on distributed databases and data sync to primary db

Tags: sql-server, ssis, alwayson, nosql

My project database is huge and there are multiple Stored Procedure jobs running based on schedule..Basically it is bottleneck for database performance. I want to distribute the load to different DB servers and merge data back to primary DB.

My question is: How do I manage this? which is the most efficient method?

My Plan : Primary database replicate data to multiple databases
Specific Jobs/SP's will be executed on replica databases
Once job done merge data (using ssis) to primary DB

Any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle it?